# Prevent pop up every time I plug in headphones in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gui, headphones

Every time I plug in headphones, this pops onto my screen:

[image: unknown audio device]

I will never, for the rest of my life, use a headset. I have no interest in this option.

Clicking **Sound Settings** does not provide the opportunity to use headphones as the default until the end of time (or any amount of time).

How might I prevent this pop up from appearing?

Comment: Yes, many of us feel your pain. See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567331/unknown-audio-device) for a discussion of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue a long time back. 
but after upgrading to the latest version of ubuntu solved this problem 
Right now I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and it this problem is solved.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new versions of Ubuntu, check out this Answer
[How to disable "Select Audio Device" pop-up on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142052/how-to-disable-select-audio-device-pop-up-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I'm not sure if it works on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu :-) Link only answers are discouraged as they might become irrelevant if the linked page changes. May I suggest you to add the steps to follow as part of your answer ?