# How to disable "Select Audio Device" pop-up on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones, devices, audio-jack

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dell XPS 9570. Every time I plug my headphones in my laptop I get this annoying pop-up that blocks the entire desktop until I select an option. It's very annoying.

[image: Select audio device pop-up]

How can I disable it? I cannot believe that in 2019 I need to specify the audio device every time I plug the headphones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using GNOME, this can be fixed using the [Remove Audio Device Selection Dialog](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1482/remove-audio-device-selection-dialog/) extension.

Comment: the extension stopped working properly for some reason

Comment: When I go to that webpage, there's a box that says "INCOMPATIBLE." I think the extension is out of date, since I'm on the latest version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Use this extension (tested on Ubuntu 22.04): https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3928/auto-select-headset/