# How to make Ubuntu detect headphones without the "Select Audio Device" prompt every time?

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio

I've had this issue with Ubuntu starting from 16.04 and it still persists in Ubuntu 20.04.

Here's the problem: whenever I plug in my headphones, it asks me to select an audio device (it gives me three options: headphones, headset and microphone), and even if I don't select one and click `Esc`, the headphones still work, so that tells me this prompt might not be necessary but I couldn't find any way to disable it.

Comment: I think there is a extension for this.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Thank you! I've found the extension and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out in the comments, there's a GNOME extension for this and after searching a bit, I found it in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142052/how-to-disable-select-audio-device-pop-up-on-ubuntu-18-04), and the extension is available [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1482/remove-audio-device-selection-dialog/)