# Default headphone device when plugging in unknown audio device

Tags: sound, 18.04, headphones, microphone, audio-jack

My laptop has a single mini-jack that handles both headphones and microphone in one port. Every time I plug in my headphones I get the following asking me what kind of device I've plugged in.

[image: this dialogue]

I'd like to set 'headphones' as a default whenever I plug in a device, so I stop getting asked each time I plug in. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/567331/unknown-audio-device

Comment: This is a confirmed bug, but still with no solution as of 16.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1297790

Comment: @K7AAY I believe when I posted this it was in relation to 16.04, however it's still an issue in 18.04.

Comment: Are you still using Unity, or have you switched to another desktop? I ask, for the 18.04 default DE is now Gnome. Also, as time permits, may I kindly beg your indulgence in adding to the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1297790  ?    Since this is a known bug for 18+ months, as per our insidiously clever master plan for world domination https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2448/are-bugs-necessarily-off-topic this is Off Topic; you will see a solution quicker by asking Launchpad to update you by email when this changes.

Comment: Is my question really that off-topic? I asked whether I could set a default device type, to which the answer is no, because of a bug. Which, to me, isn't really the same as just putting a bug report on AU. ?? Anyway, that bug report was filed over 4 years ago and is marked 'High' priority. That sounds to me like it's *totally* getting fixed. And, according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1239605, there is not supposed to be any 'set as default' for audio devices. I'm happy to let this one go.

Comment: On 22.04 now, still no solution as far as I can tell